# Create a new Modifier Type

Tags: python, modifiers

I'm discovering the wonder of this software and i'm kinda stuck with modifiers. I seems impossible to create you own Modifier with our options / action.
Every doc i find on this suggest to modify C++ code or blender at his core. Is it still the case today ? :)

Have wonderful day !

Comment: Hello ! You're right, it isn't possible to create custom modifiers with the python API. You can however explore the new Geometry Nodes workflow which aims to supersede the modifier workflow in the future. Could you elaborate on what are your goals in creating a new modifier ?

Comment: Oh multiple Reason, i'm working with Python and trying to create varieties of tools. I'm kind of new in Blender so i'm looking into possibilities. I'm more familiar with Houdini and his non destructive ways but Blender has lots of possibilities and it's Artists friendly :) 

For a tool i needed to update a list of vertex based on position. So even if you're editing the mesh you will end up with a list of pt. I'm gonna create a button with code more than a Modifier. 

But maybe you're right, with Geonode i could possibly do something ! i'm gonna take a look :) Thank you !